# Angularjs controller and view for subdomains

Tags: angularjs, subdomain

I have a website where users can reserve tickets for trains and buses. For each type of transport I use separate subdomain, also I use it for FAQ, Login page etc:

- website.com
- bus.website.com
- train.website.com
- login.website.com
- faq.website.com

I don't want to put angularjs build to each of subfolder. Instead of this I would like to have each subdomin "virtually" and have only one main folder in /var/www directory

My website has simple structure:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">...</div>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div class="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

I want each subdomain has own controller and html template. I understand that it can't be achieved by $routeProvider.

So my question: can I have main controller which decides what current subdomain is through $location, and after this instantiate both specific controller (e.g. BusController) and template (e.g. BusTemplate.html) ?

Or I am sure there is better way to leverage angularjs for subdomains.